# What is a "well-known" formula for an isometry from the hyperboloid model to the upper half-space model for hyperbolic 3-space

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry

As part of doing something else, I worked out an isometry from the hyperboloid model to the upper half-space model for hyperbolic 3-space. I did this by composing the isometry that goes from the hyperboloid to the ball model with one that goes from the ball to the upper half-space model, then computing a very long simplification of the coordinates.

I'm at a phase where I'm writing up my results for an article. I don't want to include (nor do I expect anyone to want to read) my long tedious calculation, and in hindsight I'm feeling like ... I can't possibly be the first one to have computed this.

So my question is: can anyone give me a reference where such a formula is given explicitly in coordinates? When you write it a certain way (that I'm writing it) it's actually quite elegant and simple, but this may not come out in more conventional approaches. Anyway, formula reference anyone?

---

**Added January 28, 2017:** link to my paper where I derive the formula. It's Theorem 5.2, on page 9 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06709

Comment: 3 days seems a long time for no responses to this. Maybe that computation is worth explaining in the paper after-all.

Comment: to comment anyway, I guess not many people use these two models of hyperbolic geometry side-by-side. The hyperboloid model is  "only" used in general relativity,  while the half plane model is mostly used in "analytical hyperbolic geometry" and the two subjects  are not often used together,  let alone moving from one model to the other, while your formula is maybe interesting in its own right ,  I would like to see it ,and would like to add it to both models in wikipedia. but real usage might be slight so please publish it here :)

Comment: @Willemien A notable use of the hyperboloid model in topology is the Epstein-Penner decomposition. But you are right that it's rare, and that's a reason for my wanting to explore its applications. I hesitate to post my formula here before anywhere else, being a new mathematician with no publications (yet) ... but I will post a link to the article once it's up on the arXive (soon, hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the transition from the hyperboloid model to the  Poincare ball model (to distinguish it from the projective Klein ball model :) ) is obtained by a technique equivalent to stereographic projection performed with pole coinciding with the tip of "the other" sheet of the hyperboloid onto the horisontal 3D hyper-plane tangent to the tip of the sheet of hyperboloid which represents the model of hyperbolic space. Now do the same, but instead of projecting onto the horizontal 3D hyper-plane, project onto a "tilted" 3D hyper-plane (i) passing through the tip of the sheet of the hyperboloid that modes the hyperbolic space and (ii) parallel to a 3D hyper-plane tangent to the light cone along some light-like line on the light-cone (generator line of the light-cone). Kind of analogous to the way a parabola is constructed as a conic section, by taking a plane tangent to the cone along a generator of the cone and then translated to intersect the cone.

Just to be clear, when I say "sheet" I mean a 3D sheet, i.e. a 3D hyper-surface, a 3D two-sheeted hyperboloid in the three plus one Minkowski space (four dimensional).

Isn't this construction featured in Benedetti-Petronio's book on hyperbolic geometry? Or maybe in Bill Thurston's notes on 3D manifolds, geometry and topology (alternatively, his book version of his notes)?

I am sorry I am answering too late maybe, I just came across your question.

Comment: The geometric description you give is similar to what I used to compute the formula I mention (though I did it slightly differently). The fact that one can compose isometries between the models is clear. The question is whether there's a publication that has an explicit formula written down, in coordinates. That is, let $\mathcal{I}^3\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ be the hyperboloid mode, $\mathcal{H}^3\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ the upper half-space model, and $\phi:\mathcal{I}^3\rightarrow\mathcal{H}^3$ the desired isometry. Then, is there a reference that tells us $\phi(w,x,y,z)$?

Comment: Note, I happen to know $\phi(w,x,y,z)$ but I'm not giving it here, since it's generally not smart to post new results on a forum before you publish them. My question is mainly whether I should go through the trouble of detailing my computation of that in my article, or if we can find some place where somebody has already done it. It does not occur in Benedetti-Petronio or in Thurston's notes (unless I missed it -- but I've read that stuff a lot).

Comment: @j0equ1nn I just tried to point out that the derivation is stereographic projection on Minkowski "sphere". You said you obtained yours via combination of mapping the hyperboloid model to the Poincare ball model and from the ball model to the upper half space. I simply explained how it can be done directly into the upper half space model. Maybe it will simplify your calculations. If you ask me do not write the computations in your paper, the reviewers probably know it, it is standard, no need to provide reference if you cannot find one. Anyway, this is typically a homework problem.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but regardless of one's opinion on the triviality of the computation, the formula is not written down in any existing literature as far as I can tell. It seems a valid point that if one is going to use a formula, there should be at least one available instance of it being derived. It does not seem a good standard to expect one's reader to take a formula on faith and give them the verification as "homework."

Comment: @j0equ1nn No, only because a formula is not in the literature, doesn't mean reviewers would want to see it. I have encountered this situation many times and reviewers usually insist on removing such proofs from articles because "it is clear, we know it's true, no need to waste peoples' time and article space, making the article longer than necessary".

Comment: @j0equ1nn you can write the article with a derivation for the ArXiv, and omit the derivation for the submission. You can simply reference the ArXiv one. I do that sometimes, because I occasionally develop algorithmic recipes out of theoretical geometric or physical models and to implement these recipes you need to know how to handle some smaller details. However, reviewers do not care to read them, while people who implement keep asking about them. The ArXiv method works the best.

Comment: Ey that sounds like a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: I've added the link to my paper where the formula is derived.